# import tables from another server of SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL servers i have to import data from server1 to server2 everyday but the problem is all records are getting import which are already in server2 i m not able to compare Primary key which is my EmpID to another table

Answer (score 0):

You can define a linked server and then you'll be able to compare both tables through simple querying to decide what records you still need to synchronise.

[Creating a linked server (clickety)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

Your query should end up looking something like...

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT *
FROM anothertableonmylinkedserver
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM   mytable
                  WHERE  mytable.primarykey = anothertableonmylinkedserver.primarykey)
```

Comment: I Execute this Query                                                                                          (insert into server1.DB.Table from server2.DB.Table) But all entries are getting add everytime so i have to set a where condition on Primary key so that no duplicacy can occur

Comment: primary key is my EmpID